# How can I get stdlib.jar working in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

After some hours of researching i still have a problem with my stdlib. I've imported lib just like it says on this link (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206850425-How-to-use-a-external-jar-in-a-Java-application) but it still not working. When I type `StdDraw.setScale(-100, 100);` set scale goes red and intellij says "can't resolve symbol". I'm adding some screenshots so you can see what's the problem. And ignore name of Java classes i'm SLovenian haha ;-)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSNQY.png)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The link you shared states there is a problem with package/class definition in stdlib.jar.

Comment: You can't import a class that is not located in a package. What is this stdlib jar you're talking about? Where does it come from?

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207703065-How-to-use-stdlib-jar-in-Intellij-Idea- for the solution.

Comment: Thanks for answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you tried with project structure > add libraries > stdlib.jar and not working consider this:
I had the same problem and after a deep search I found the reason. You have to use a different stdlib.jar file. Download this [stdlib-package](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/stdlib-package.jar) and add `import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.StdDraw;`on the top of your .java file. (you can change StdDraw, Draw, StdIn, etc on top, your compiler will probably help you to import the right libraries)

Answer (score 0):

OK I get it. Just import StdDraw class in src of your project and don't use a package. Then it starts to work fine.