# How can I get stdlib.jar to work in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, std, libraries

I​ had used the IntelliJ IDEA installer provided in [the booksite for Computer Science: An Interdisciplinary Approach](https://lift.cs.princeton.edu/java/windows/) and I had no problem to use the library. However, I noticed that installation had screwed my Git bash display settings, so I uninstalled everything.

Later, I installed the latest version of IntelliJ (2021.3.3), from [the JetBrains website](https://www.jetbrains.com/es-es/idea/download/#section=windows) and apparently all the previous settings were overwritten, since I could no longer use the library. So, I downgraded back to the version provided in the booksite, however, I still can't use the Std library.

I've tried adding the versions of the library .jar files that I found:

- [On the Standard Libraries Princeton's webpage](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/)
- [On the Jar Download website](https://jar-download.com/artifact-search/stdlib)
- [On this post from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59111159/how-can-i-get-stdlib-jar-working-in-intellij)
- [In the .jar file from the hello.zip file I found on this other Princeton webpage](https://lift.cs.princeton.edu/java/windows/)

Together and independently to the module and libraries, via IntelliJ IDEA, following the paths: "File > Project settings > Modules > + > JARs or directories" and "File > Project settings > Libraries > + > Java" , respectively, and choosing the corresponding directory/file, with no luck, since I've got the "cannot find symbol" error message:

```
Barnsley.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        StdDraw.setScale(-0.1, 1.1);              // leave a 10% border
        ^
  symbol:   variable StdDraw
  location: class Barnsley
```

For literally every single mention of the Std libraries in the code. I​ also tried editing the environment system variables and created a variable named "CLASSPATH" and linked it to the Stdlib.jar file and then, to the .lift folder that came with the hello.zip file, from the first week assignment. Again, no luck, because I kept getting the same error message.

Next up, I typed:

javac -cp stdlib.jar Barnsley.java

In the command line, and although that command itself didn't lead to any error message, when I tried to run the program, typing:

```
java -cp stdlib.jar Barnsley 10000
```

This error message showed up:

Error: Could not find or load main class Barnsley
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Barnsley

I also vainly tried copying and pasting every .java file [from Standard libraries webpage](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/) to the same directory where I keep the program files.

I know some (maybe lots of people) have asked the same or a similar question before, either here or in other forums, but I've been googling and looking for a solution for three days now and, as you can see, none of the reported solutions that I've found have been of help to me, that's why I decided to ask again, on my own.

Thank you for reading my post and/or for any help you can provide.

PS.: The Barnsley.java file in the error messages corresponds to the one provided in the 5th section of [this webpage from the booksite.](https://lift.cs.princeton.edu/java/windows/)

[Edit - April 7th, 2022]:
I tried to follow @CrazyCoder advice, so I created a folder named "src", extracted all the files from the stdlib.jar file that came with the hello.zip file into src and also moved Barnsley.java to that folder. Next, Next, I tried to follow the instructions from [the webpage he mentioned](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html), as shown in the following screenshot:
[image: New roject settings]

And somehow, got the same error message when compiling:
[image: Error message screenshot]

I don't know what went wrong :C Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

[Edit - Later on April 7th, 2022]:

Something weird happened. I downloaded the file provided by @CrazyCorder and there was a warning about Amazon Corretto not being installed, that I decided to ignore.

I tried to run the program from the command line, with no luck, because I got the same error message as always. So, I noticed that there was no JDK assigned to the SDK slot in the Project structure, and I chose to use JDK 18 (following the path "File > Project structure > Project"), which is the one that I had previously installed on my computer, but that didn't really change a thing.

Lastly, I tried to run it from the IDE and that's when it finally worked!!! So, thank you, @CrazyCoder :D I still don't know why it doesn't work from the command line, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also vainly tried copying and pasting every .java file from Standard libraries webpage to the same directory where I keep the program files.

This works just fine, you need to place all the `.java` files from the `stdlib.jar` into the [sources root directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html) (marked in blue in the project view). `Barnsley.java` needs to be in the same directory.

[image: works fine]

The jar with `.class` files will not work in the dependencies/classpath as you [cannot import classes from the default package in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283816/how-to-access-java-classes-in-the-default-package).

It was an extremely poor choice to keep the classes in the default package and it's the fault of the creators of this library/course. This simple oversight has caused major headaches over the years.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @CrazyCoder! Could you please add more details on how you managed to make it work? As you can see from the edit, I tried to follow your instructions, but I keep getting the same error message :(

Comment: Works fine here: https://i.imgur.com/u34XXS5.png. I copied only .java files there, not .class files. You can also build and run it directly from the IDE, you don't need to use the terminal: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-applications.html. Here is the complete working project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/445sz8ml3d31pea/hello-stdlib.zip?dl=1.

Comment: running it from the IDE worked this time but for some reason, the same error message keeps showing up everytime I try to run it from the command line. Any idea about why could that be? In either case, thank you so much, I was about to pull out my hair with this thing!

Comment: I don't know why command line javac doesn't work for you. Could be some broken or different Java version. I'm using OpenJDK 11 in the command line and it works fine with the project I shared.